# Godot 4 animation player not playing animation (3D)

Tags: 3d, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

So, I am new to 3D godot, I was following a 3rd person controller tutorial, and I tried to add my own animations and a different character model, the character model works fine, but the animation player won't even play the animations in the editor.

code:

```
extends CharacterBody3D

@onready var camera_mount = $CameraMount
@onready var animation_player = $visuals/mixamo_base/AnimationPlayer
@onready var visuals = $visuals


var SPEED = 2.8
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 4.5

var walking_speed = 3.0
var running_speed = 5.0

var running = false
var is_locked = false

@export var sense_horizontal = 0.3
@export var sense_vertical = 0.3

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")


func _ready():
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
    
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * sense_horizontal))
        visuals.rotate_y(deg_to_rad(event.relative.x * sense_horizontal))
        camera_mount.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.y * sense_vertical))

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    if !animation_player.is_playing():
        is_locked = false
        print("THE HECK IS WRONG WITH THIS?!??!?!??!?!?!??!?!?")
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("kick"):
        if animation_player.current_animation != "kick":
            animation_player.play("kick")
            is_locked = true
            
    if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
        SPEED = running_speed
        running = true
    else:
        running = false
        SPEED = walking_speed
    
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        if !is_locked:
            if running:
                if animation_player.current_animation != "running":
                    animation_player.play("running")
            else:
                if animation_player.current_animation != "walking":
                    animation_player.play("walking")
                    print("THE HECK IS WRONG WITH THIS?!??!?!??!?!?!??!?!?")
                    
            visuals.look_at(position + direction)
            
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        if !is_locked:
            if animation_player.current_animation != "idle":
                animation_player.play("idle")
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)  
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)
    if !is_locked:
        move_and_slide()
```

If you notice the random print statements saying THE HECK IS WRONG WITH THIS, that is my attempt at debugging, the print statements print out the text, but the animations won't play.

[image of node structuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNdmp.png)

I have tried searching around on google, but I haven't found anybody with the same problem.

As you can see above, I tried print debugging + tweaking code, nothing has worked

Comment: Note: it doesn't even play the first frame of the animation (similar to other problems)